# UIcollectionViewCells behave abnormal when changes its layout attribute

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want view like safari recent tabs.

[image]

I am able to create upto some extent but if the number of cells increasing it looks like

[image]

and also when I select any cell then it is not returning correct index path.

Here is the code what I uses

```
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

  NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
  NSInteger total = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];



UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attr = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];



attr.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 20, 350);

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0/-500;

if (indexPath.row+1 == total)
{
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0, (CARD_SPACING * index), 15);
    attr.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
else
{
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0, (CARD_SPACING * index), 0);
    attr.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -(M_PI*18)/180, 1, 0, 0);
}


return attr;
}
```

This is just a rough code. Can anyone please help me whether I am on right way or not. As I am creating custom layout first time.

If this complete code is not right please tell me the suitable way to achive it.

This code works fine for 3 or 4 cells but as I increase the number of cells it looks odd.